# Bind serve to IPV6 address instead of the default IPV4

Tags: reactjs, npm, serve

I've deployed a React application and am running the build using Serve, following the React doc's [Deployment Page](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

The problem I've run into is that Serve, by default, picks up the IPV4 address of the machine. I need it to pick the IPV6 one. This is my first time deploying an app, and being completely new to Serve and Node in general, I've not been able to figure out how to do so and would appreciate some guidance and help.

I used `serve -h` to understand whether I can do something and tried running this

`serve -s build -l tcp://<ipv6-address>:<port-number>`

When I run this I get the following error

```
Error: Failed to serve: Error: listen EINVAL: invalid argument 
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1468:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1533:12)
    at doListen (node:net:1682:7)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
    at Server.<anonymous> (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/serve/build/main.js:236:11)
```